# Spring Data Elasticsearch: Multiple Index with same Document

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch and for the beginning everything works fine.

```
@Document( type = "products", indexName = "empty" )
public class Product
{
...
}

public interface ProductRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String>
{
...
}
```

In my model i can search for products.

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository repository;
...
repository.findByIdentifier( "xxx" ).getCategory() );
```

So, my problem is - I've the same Elasticsearch type in different indices and I want to use the same document for all queries. I can handle more connections via a pool - but I don't have any idea how I can implement this.

I would like to have, something like that:

```
ProductRepository customerRepo = ElasticsearchPool.getRepoByCustomer("abc", ProductRepository.class);
repository.findByIdentifier( "xxx" ).getCategory();
```

Is it possible to create a repository at runtime, with an different index ?

Thanks a lot
Marcel

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It's possible with Spring. But you should use [ElasticsearchTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html) instead of `Repository`.

For example. I have two products. They are stored in different indices.

```
@Document(indexName = "product-a", type = "product")
public class ProductA {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private int value;

    //Getters and setters
}

@Document(indexName = "product-b", type = "product")
public class ProductB {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

Suppose if they have the same type, so they have the same fields. But it's not necessary. Two products can have totally different fields.

I have two repositories:

```
public interface ProductARepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ProductA, String> {
}


public interface ProductBRepository
    extends ElasticsearchRepository<ProductB, String> {


}
```

It's not necessary too. Only for testing. The fact that `ProductA` is stored in "product-a" index and `ProductB` is stored in "product-b" index.

**How to query two(ten, dozen) indices with the same type?**

Just build custom repository like this

```
@Repository
public class CustomProductRepositoryImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public List<ProductA> findProductByName(String name) {
        MatchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("name", name);

        //You can query as many indices as you want
        IndicesQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.indicesQuery(queryBuilder, "product-a", "product-b");

        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(builder).build();

        return elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, response -> {
            SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
            List<ProductA> result = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays.stream(hits.getHits()).forEach(h -> {
                Map<String, Object> source = h.getSource();
                //get only id just for test
                ProductA productA = new ProductA()
                        .setId(String.valueOf(source.getOrDefault("id", null)));
                result.add(productA);
            });
            return result;
        });
    }

}
```

You can search as many indices as you want and you can transparently inject this behavior into `ProductARepository` [adding custom behavior to single repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)

Second solution is to use [indices aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), but you had to create custom model or custom repository too.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [the `withIndices` method](http://javadox.com/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch/1.3.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/NativeSearchQueryBuilder.html#withIndices-java.lang.String...-) to switch the index if needed:

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = nativeSearchQueryBuilderConfig.getNativeSearchQueryBuilder();
// Assign the index explicitly.
nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices("product-a");
// Then add query as usual.
nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(allQueries)
```

The `@Document` annotation in entity will only clarify the mapping, to query against a specific index, we still need to use above method.

```
@Document(indexName="product-a", type="_doc")
```