# Get data from 3 different indexes in the Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I was successfully able to get data from an individual index, but now I will have to get the data from 3 indexes, those 3 indexes are of different types `(Student, Employee, School)`. With a single query trigger can I be able to get data from all the three index.

Comment: Each index has only one type or multiple?

Comment: each index has only one type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In es you can specify that by URL

```
POST /gb,us/user,tweet/_search
{
//YOur query
}
```

In your case if you have one type per index it could be

```
POST /Student,Employee,School/_search
```

More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html)

In Java according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466200/spring-data-elasticsearch-multiple-index-with-same-document) you should have smth like this

```
QueryBuilders.indicesQuery(queryBuilder, "product-a", "product-b");
```

Comment: ty so much. I forgot to mention i was looking for JAVA API :)

Comment: There should be method set indices :)

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth which librarry are you using?

Comment: This is what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot :)