# Elasticsearch: search for two different document in a single query

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have two entities Merchant and Customer:

```
public class Merchant{
  private UUID id;
  private String name;
  //... other fields and getters/setters
}    

public class Customer{
      private UUID id;
      private String name;
      //... other fields and getters/setters
    }
```

These two entities are sightly different from each-other.

What I'am trying to to do is when I search with the term "John" I want to get both a merchant named "John Market" and a customer called "John Smith".

To achieve this I indexed these entities to a single index.

```
@Document(indexName = "merchant_customer_index", type = "merchantorcustomer")
public class MerchantOrCustomer {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private int type;
    //...
```

My query can return both Merchant and Customer:

```
List<MerchantOrCustomer> result = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, MerchantOrCustomer.class);
```

I distinguish them programmatic(`if(result.get(i).getType() == 0` we received Merchant `else` Customer)
Then use their id to extract actual object from relational db.

I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything that can help to estimate if it is a good practice. Is it a good practice?

Please, give me a hint if there is a better way.

Comment: What if object with same `id` is both merchant and customer?

Comment: I think id is UUID. So, should be good, if done correctly.

Comment: @nitzien I mean what if one entity acts in both roles in application: sells stuff and buys stuff? Then I think elasticsearch will store only one object for that given `id` in index.

Comment: I agree now @Ivan

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you did unless there is some collusion as mentioned by @Ivan in comments. 
Here is another possible way to do if you were using elasticTemplate- [Spring Data Elasticsearch: Multiple Index with same Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466200/spring-data-elasticsearch-multiple-index-with-same-document?noredirect=1&lq=1) or if you are using queryBuilder - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html