# Spring boot elastic search repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

I have several indices where I save products:

```
product-example1
product-example2
product-example3
product-example4 
product-example5
```

I have the a document in elastic search that has the same structure and it can used for different indices:

```
@Data
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "", type = "", createIndex = false)
public class ProductDocument {

@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private String seller;
private String releaseDate;
....
}
```

So basically I want to use same settings, same mappings same search service. 
So I made `indexName` and  `type` parametric in spring boot java, instead of creating 5 classes extending `ProductDocument` ?

```
@Autowired
private final ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;  

this.elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex("product-example1", loadFile("/files/settings.json"));
this.elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping("product-example1", "product-type1",   loadFile("/files/mapping.json"));

this.elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex("product-example2", loadFile("/files/settings.json"));
this.elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping("product-example2", "product-type2",   loadFile("/files/mapping.json"));   

......
```

Now I want to create a ProductRepository but I don't have a class  with defined index name. If I use generic class:

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ProductDocument, String> {
}
```

I get the error  which is totally understable cause I created the index names in dynamic way: 
`lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Unknown indexName. Make sure the indexName is defined. e.g @ProductDocument(indexName="foo")`

So is it possible somehow to create repository for indexes that I created in dynamic way as described above, and pass the index name and type as parameter ?

Please help! I'm stuck.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466200/spring-data-elasticsearch-multiple-index-with-same-document

Comment: I checked this but it created a class for each index and  I don't want that. I want to create a repository for each index without creating a specific class for each one? @SandOfTime

Comment: @SandOfTime do you have any other suggestion?